# Getting error scrollable result sets are not enabled for hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Getting error scrollable result sets are not enabled

We are getting "scrollable result sets are not enabled" in prod, the error is random, sometimes it works and sometimes we get the error. Can someone please help.

```
private ScrollableResults scrollableResults() {
        return configureCriteria().setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE).setFetchSize(batchSize).setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL).setReadOnly(readonly).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    }
```

Comment: Any chance you are getting this after db restart? Did you try forcing hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset to true ?

Comment: There was a DB restart, but we are seeing this type of error recently, our code is out there for more than 2 years, we have getting this frequently in last 10 days, I have not tried hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset, will try it

Comment: @KuldeepJadhav  im facing same issue lately (random nature).
did "hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset" work at your end ? or you found any other solution ?